# Can I create new iOS app from my existing app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have made a language learning App - English to Japanese. and its live in app store now.

Now I want to use my old app to make a new one , example : Farsi to Japanese .

Can I use my old app and change text and name ? by name I mean bundle id name .
Please tell me how can I do it and what are the fields need to be changed.
Visual would be awesome since I'm very new and learning with udemy and had even hard time to find solution to my basic question here ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new target for under your current project for another project and change the bundle identifier.Separate Info.plist will be created so you can manage it specifically for this target. It will be easy to maintain, if there are not many differences. Below is how to create new target from existing target:

[image]

Comment: I tried but since I have a new account I dont have that feature yet. I'm going to ask one more question if you'll help with that would be awesome

Comment: Oh ok. I got it. No problem. Sure, let me know what question you have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,of course you can make/modify your existing app. Just you have to choose what to make changes in your existing sourcecode. You can also refer to youtube or any other platform from where you can get idea.

Comment: If you were me, and wanted to ask this question . how would you ask it ? I tried to find videos in youtube but its showing me how to create a new app and nothing about using your existing app to create a brand new one